# How to get phase angle from FFT for an amplitude modulated signal

Tags: matlab, fft, phase

I have the measurements of an amplitude modulated signal. I analysed with the **fft()** matlab function. After I calculate everything by "the book", I have only one problem. The phase of the modulated signal is not ok. Only if I subtract `pi/2` form the calculated phase, I get the correct value. The modulated signal is the sixth component:

> X[6]= -8.2257e+001 -1.6158e+002i 
>   phase(x[6])=atan(-8.2257e+001/-1.6158e+002)= 1.0999

The true phase is: `pahse(x[6])-pi/2 = -0.4709`

Why i have to subtract `pi/2`?[image: if i use <code>atan2(imag(X(6)),real(X(6)))</code>]
[image: if i use <code>atan(imag(X(6))/real(X(6)))-pi/2</code>]

if i use `atan2(imag(X(6)),real(X(6)))` - first image

if i use `atan(imag(X(6))/real(X(6)))-pi/2` - second image

Comment: Are you using `atan` or `atan2`? You're code uses `atan` but you've tagged `atan2`.

Comment: sorry my mistake, there is no atan tag, but i'm using the atan() fnc.

Comment: Use `atan2` then. Problem solved.

Comment: Like @Rody Oldenhuis suggested, but that nether works `atan2(imagX,realX)=-2.04` but the phase is **-0.4709** as i mentioned above.

Comment: Are you sure the measurement didn't assume cosines where you use sines, or vice versa, or something? Based on those numbers, it's the *measurement's* phases which are incorrect...

Answer (score 7):

You are experiencing quadrant ambiguity. The range of `atan()` is `[-pi/2 ... +pi/2]` with repetitions when going outside that range. This means, you cannot uniquely determine the correct quadrant of your angle, when that angle happens to be on the "other side" of the circle.

To avoid this sort of thing, use `angle` (or `phase`) and/or `atan2` (the 4-quadrant version of `atan`):

```
>> X = -8.2257e+001 - 1.6158e+002i;
>> angle(X)
ans =
   -2.041680802478084e+000
>> atan2(imag(X), real(X))
ans =
   -2.041680802478084e+000
```

Comment: second `ans =-2.0...` but if i run with this code i have a larger phase difference then earlier. I know for sure that the result should be  **-0.4709**

Comment: @Elod: just look at your values -- minus 80 something in `x` direction (real axis) and minus 160-something in `y` direction (imaginary axis), that's an angle of roughly 45 degrees *beyond* negative 90 degrees, therefore, roughly minus 135 degrees (-2.3 something radians). So your  -0.4 radians just don't make any sense...

Comment: I totally understand and agree with you, however if i use that phase shift the result is the first image attached to my post.